# How to hide text which is not inside HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

```
<div class="padd10_m">
<a href="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/user-profile/admin/" class="grid_view_url_thing1">admin</a> 
US <img src="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/images/flags/us.png">                
</div>
```

In the above code I want to hide "US" word. I hide that image after US but unable to find the way to hide this "US" word. what could be the code to hide it?

Comment: Can't you just delete the word "US"?

Comment: You can't address it so you can't hide it.

Comment: I wish if I could do that so easily. All i have is wordpress access, no cpanel.

Comment: add a tag around it. If you need to exert control on some portion of content, this portion has to be reflected in document structure. Otherwise, it has no particular attributes to work with.

Comment: Could be accessed using `document.querySelector('.padd10_m').childNodes`

Comment: Add a `span` tag around US text, and target that span using css like `.padd10_m>span: display:none;`.

Comment: where as I know this word come through javascript or something like this.

Comment: thanx Rayon.. seems like a nice idea.
thanx to Rasmus, aavrug,  Vladimir, Mr_Green and deepak as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```css
.padd10_m {
  font-size: 0px;
}
.padd10_m > * {
  font-size: 14px;
  /* Apply normal font again */
}
```

```html
<div class="padd10_m">
  <a href="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/user-profile/admin/" class="grid_view_url_thing1">admin</a> US
  <img src="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/images/flags/us.png">
</div>
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfbxb4v5/)**

### Or

If you want to go with JavaScript (*I don't see why though*), Here is the solution:

```js
var pad = document.querySelector('.padd10_m');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(pad.childNodes, function(el) {
  if (el.nodeType === 3) {   // check if it is text node
    pad.removeChild(el);     // remove the text node
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="padd10_m">
  <a href="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/user-profile/admin/" class="grid_view_url_thing1">admin</a> US
  <img src="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/images/flags/us.png">
</div>
```

Comment: well this could be a good idea, if "US" is the only word in it. But it contains another text as well

Comment: @RasikaWadibhasme any example of what you mean?

Comment: all i mean is if u see in <div class="padd10_m"> i have content in <a> tag. if i m putting font-size:0px to padd10_m class, will it affect to <a> tag as well?
if not, then this will work for me

Comment: @RasikaWadibhasme it won't affect `a` tag. I am again applying the normal font-size to it.

Answer (score 2):

Use css:

```
.padd10_m { font-size: 0; }
.padd10_m * { font-size: 1rem;}
```

Comment: greattoo.. its looking somthing new to me.
does this * will work?

Comment: I think it should. It mean applying font size of  to all children of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to hide with `font-size`

```css
.padd10_m{font-size:0;}
.padd10_m > a{font-size:16px;}
```

```html
<div class="padd10_m">
  <a href="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/user-profile/admin/" class="grid_view_url_thing1">admin</a> US
  <img src="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/images/flags/us.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
   .padd10_m {
    font-size:0px;
    }

    .padd10_m a{
    font-size:14px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="padd10_m">
<a href="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/user-profile/admin/" class="grid_view_url_thing1">admin</a> 
US <img src="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/images/flags/us.png">                
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the image (US-Flag) over the Text:

```
.padd10_m img {
    margin: 0 0 -7px -25px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

In addition you can set the font color at same as background color.

```css
img {
    margin: 0 0 -7px -25px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="padd10_m">
<a href="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/user-profile/admin/" class="grid_view_url_thing1">admin</a> 
US <img src="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/images/flags/us.png">                
</div>
```

**Update:** I didn't realized that the image also should be hidden. Here another solution:

```css
.padd10_m {
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="padd10_m">
<a href="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/user-profile/admin/" class="grid_view_url_thing1">admin</a> 
US <img src="http://www.caviarandfriends.com/job_board/wp-content/themes/PricerrTheme/images/flags/us.png">                
</div>
```

Comment: thanx andy but i dont want that flag as well. :P

Answer (score 1):

Adding :after, you can add a space between admin and the flag.

```
.padd10_m{
  font-size: 0px;
}

.padd10_m a{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.padd10_m a:after{
  content: ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/US <img/g, '<img');
</script>
```

Boom